# How can I enhance my auto hide script in Google Sheets so it wont time out

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I run on multiple Spreadsheets... it auto hides rows that contain a certain value.  Currently this script it setup to run daily around 3:00 am, to ensure no one is active in it while it processes.  The issue is I am now running into is these sheets are getting too large to use my current script, which runs line by line.  The script times out and doesn't finish.  I'm guessing it still runs the script on all the lines that are already hidden.

Here is my current script, which is pretty basic:

```
function autoHide() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHIPPING");

      //get data from column 
  var data = sheet.getRange('AD:AD').getValues();

      //iterate over all rows
  for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
      //compare first character, if greater than 0, then hide row
    if(data[i][0] > 0){
      sheet.hideRows(i+1);

    }
  }
}
```

I have tried searching for better options, and found where people were talking about using array filters, or running in batches, just different things that didn't seem to be explained enough for me to translate to what I was working on.  I know running this line by line isn't the best way, especially with over a 1,000 rows and growing.

For a best case scenario, I would like to have a very efficient script that uses fractions of the processing my current script does.  Otherwise, if there was just a way to run the script on the rows that are visible, that would be almost as good.  Worst case scenario, if there is just a way to tell it to pick up where it left off when it gave a time out error... by placing some type of tag or something to know where to start back up.

I don't think linking a sheet is necessary, I just need to be able to hide any row that has a number greater than 0 in column AD, on a sheet called "SHIPPING".

Comment: Do you have many blank rows below the data? You should test only through the end of data using getLastRow().

Comment: I do have blank rows below the data.  While I agree this will be a good addition to add, the problem itself is that this script times out before it gets halfway through the current data.  So it doesn't even make it to that point.

Answer (score 0):

While you could speed up the script itself (for example by batching consecutive rows that need to be hidden) that will also evenctually time out.
Instead, your script should remember in script properties the last row it processed, ao that if the script times out it will continue starting from that row.
You will also need to change the trigger times. Make it run every 10 minutes but only start processing if 1) its past 3am and b) the last row processed is not yet the very last row (which you reset to zero when finished).
this should handle huge sheets just fine. by 5am it would have run 12 times since 3am so it should be able to process 12 times more rows.
Note I chose 10min trigger so that a previous trigger (which could run for 6 minutes) wont ever overlap the next trigger.
Do make sure to set your timezone in the sheet and script file properties so that you use your timezones when checking if its past 3am already.

Comment: That does sound like the best solutions then... to start up from the last row processed.  Good suggestions on setting triggers 10 minutes apart too.

I will look into some script examples to incorporate these suggestions into my current script.  If you happen to have some links or examples handy, that would also be appreciated.