# Read body for all messages in a gmail thread without timing out

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

This is my code

```
var threads = GmailApp.search('label:X');
var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);
for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    var message = messages[i][0].getPlainBody();
    if (message == null) {
        message = messages[i][0].getBody();
    }
    //Utilities.sleep(1000);
}
```

Without the Utilities.sleep method I get service invoked too many times error.

```
Service invoked too many times in a short time: gmail rateMax. Try Utilities.sleep(1000) between calls.
```

With the Utilities.sleep method I get exceeded maximum time error.

```
Exceeded maximum execution time
```

The label has about 400 threads. What is the optimized way of reading the body of the first message in each thread?

Answer (score 1):

While you could tinker with using a smaller sleep value , the script is ok, it just takes that much time to process so many messages. Instead you need to remember in script properties the index that you are processing and only process say 50 each time. Then a time trigger can handle calling many times until done. See this other answer which is similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/30125776/2213940

Comment: I have tried that. I have tried reducing the time. Sleeping every 5 or 10 iterations and everytime I encounter those errors. The only solution i see is splinting up the task.

Comment: That's what my answer says, to split it